# Possible algorithms to solve this problem

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, nlp

I have a list of extracted names of one hotel , and these are the names taken by n websites about the same hotel . The list contains m names about 1 hotel . I have to select one name from the list based on correctness , similarity , less mistakes . How can I achieve this ?
Any direction is helpful .

Example: List of names for hotelId 1 {"ABC Hotel","CDE hotel" , "Hotel ABC" ,"AB Hotel" , "Hotel BCA" ...}

With the initital research it looks like a graph related problem

Comment: How can you compute "correctness", "similarity", "mistakes", etc.?  Do have anything more in mind which you might find obvious (but I don't)?  Currently this doesn't look like a programming problem (connecting information cleverly) but a problem of finding out more about the situation (gathering information).

Comment: We have different components for different aggregation , we have the similar problem for addresses as well . n addresses for 1 hotel and one to be chosen.

Comment: The attributes we have are addresses , geo locations , descriptions etc

Answer (score 0):

This is not gonna work. You will not get similarities based on the names. Especially if almost every hotel has the keyword hotel in its name.

You need more information to match similarities.
Address, Geo location, attributes about the hotel could also help (wifi, parking, close to beach, pool), if this is a chain and so on. The more information you have the better the matching result you can get.

Comment: Well we have more information about hotels but that has to be aggregated as well , like for address aggregation we get n addresses about the same hotelId , one to be choosen . 
Same applies to Geo location and other attributes .

Comment: This would have been a great comment, but for an answer it lacks the answering aspect.

Comment: @Alfe the information we have related to hotels are , addresses , geo locations , tags, descriptions , names , pictures , city , country. 
But all this information can be same or different for one particular hotel as they are extracted from n places.

Comment: Easiest graph would be to add the hotels with all the data to a search engine like elasticsearch. Let them calculate matching scores between hotels. The score could be the distance or an edge between the hotel nodes. And just take hotels into relation ship which have a score higher then factor X. But for this you don't need a graph database. This would just show you one possibility of hotels which could be similar to each other. What is your goal to get it into a graph?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to leverage some of Bing or Google APIs --> i.e. do a search for the hotel name with some details from address in Search APIs or in some Map APIS (e.g. search for ["ABC Hotel 5AV Philliadelphia","CDE hotel 5AV Philliadelphia" , "Hotel ABC 5AV Philliadelphia",..] then compare your data with the API response.